# Como remover background usando python e cv2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, background-image

Sou iniciante em programação e estou alguns problemas ao tentar remover o fundo da imagem usando cv2. O programa abaixo roda, porém o resultado não é o esperado. Gostaria de ajuda a melhorar..

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('001.tif')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray,5)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

contours, hierarchy =     
cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

h, w = img.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)


cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt],-1, 255, -1)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)


cv2.imwrite('002.png', res)
cv2.imshow('img', res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Com a execução do código, essa imagem: 
[image: Antes]

E após o código: 
[image: Depois]

Answer (score -1):

[Chris Albon](https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/preprocessing_images/remove_backgrounds/)  explica bem este processo, para seu caso você deve especificar um retângulo que cobrirá a imagem como por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usando o seguinte retângulo:

```
rectangle = (121, 66, 158, 493)
```

Consegui este resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]